# Python faulthandler show error window

Tags: python, pyqt

I might be totally overlooking something but is there a way to show a custom error window when while using the `faulthandler` package.

Currently I'm just writing to a log file using:

```
faulthandler.enabled(file=open("crash.log", "w"))
```

however it would be really nice to be able to show some kind of window to the user with an error message.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the behaviour of [faulthandler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler) to do something different other than log faults to a file-like object according to the [documetnation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html)

However you can change [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) and use a [`PyQt4.QtGui.QMessageBox`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmessagebox.html)

**Example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys


from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow, QMessageBox


class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        sys.excepthook = self._displayError

    def _error(self, etype, evalue, etraceback):
        QMessageBox.critical(
            self,
            "ERROR",
            "An unexpected error occurred: {0:s}".format(evalue)
        )
```